# Google Adwords call tracking is not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-ads-api

I'm working in WordPress to setup google adwords call tracking functionality in my site. and I setup all the setups which are defined in below link

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6095883?hl=en

follow these steps to do setup:-

1. Firstly created a campaign
2. `Ad extensions` to add contact number for campaign
   [image]
3. Then create Conversion and below is the screenshot of this
   [image]
4. It provides me some javascript code to add in header and add its function in body onload. follow this url

   https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6095883?hl=en
5. Now change contact number of all the places.

I did all the things which are required. But it is not working.. is anyone have any idea what I'm missing. It will be very helpful for me.

Thanks in Advance.